# Is this set closed under addition or multiplication or both

Tags: group-theory

There is a show on our cable network called "the challenge" on which the following question was asked of high school students.

Is the set {-1, 0, 1} closed under:
1) addition 
2) multiplication
3) both
4) neither

The student's answer was "both" but the moderator said the "correct" answer was "addition". I may be missing something obvious but wasn't the student correct?

Comment: Neither the student nor the moderator gave the correct answer.

Comment: If these are integers with standard addition and multiplication, then this set is **only** closed under multiplication. Note that $1+1=2$ is not in the set.

Comment: This set is only closed under multiplication.

Comment: Was the moderator a mathematician?  If not, can he honestly claim to be qualified for the job?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $1+1=2$ ... But you may think the set $\{ -1 , 0 ,1\}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where $1+1=2=-1$. It depends on what you mean by "$+$". If you don't specify the definition of the laws, the answer is "maybe".

Comment: For $\times$ defined "as usual", the set is stable.

Answer (score 1):

If mod-3 addition was intended, then "both" would be the right answer, but I see no reasonable way to say that it's not closed under multiplication.